# Проблема с программами для снятия скриншотов [Arch Linux]

Tags: linux, archlinux, screenshots

С недавних пор возникла проблема со скриншотами на Arch Linux.

```
 ОС: Arch Linux
 Видеокарта: Intel HD Graphics 620
 Драйвер: xf86-video-intel
 Окружение: GNOME 3
```

Первое проявление было в `Joxi`. Думал, что дело в софте, удалил программу и забыл на какое-то время. Сейчас снова появилась потребность в скриншотах, но так как проблема с `Joxi` не решилась, а функционала стандартного скриншотера gnome мне не хватало, стал искать другие варианты. Выбор пал на `Shutter`, но проблема появилась и на нем.

Суть:

В `Joxi` при взятии скриншота области или же полного экрана на выходе получается просто черный экран.

В `Shutter` на выходе получается вот такая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть предположения в чем может быть причина?
Обновление драйвера не помогает.

З.Ы. Ранее `Joxi` работал абсолютно адекватно, особых изменений до появления проблемы в системе не делалось.

Comment: Полная переустановка GNOME не помогла, буду копать дальше.

Comment: *ksnapshot* обычно работает, глюки как правило из-за видеодрайвера.

Comment: @0andriy но он под KDE, разве нет?

Comment: У меня KDE нет примерно лет 10, а `ksnapshot` использую время от времени до сих пор.

Comment: @0andriy поискал его в репозиториях, как я понял, `ksnapshot` теперь называется `spectacle`. Он у меня также не заработал. Видимо, дело все-таки в драйвере, так что буду копать в эту сторону.

Comment: Попробуйте ещё лайтшот: https://prnt.sc/
отлично работает, правда через вайн